# How would you "compress" a list?

Tags: java, performance, list

For instance say I have a list with the following values

```
{"A", null, null, "B", null, "C", null, "D", "E", null}
```

What would be the most efficient way to compress that to

```
{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"}
```

Is there a way to do this quickly and efficiently without creating a new list altogether.  It would also be fine if the compressed list looked like

```
{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", null, null, null, null, null}
```

Comment: Iterate over the list removing any `null` reference. You can do this easily with an `Iterator`

Comment: Implement `interface Comparable` then use Collections.sort(yourList) make null greater than not null and you will get version 2 of your list.

Comment: Another option: create a list wrapper that ignores add(null)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most efficient I know of, in terms of code efficiency, is

```
list.removeAll( Collections.singleton(null) );
```

Comment: Can't claim original credit - just remember doing this at some point and saying 'damn, that's witty.'

Answer (score 1):

Could use this simple loop to remove all null Elements

```
while(aList.remove(null)) {/*do nothing */};
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's truly a Java List (and not an Array), it should automatically relink the elements in the List when you remove an element.

So in { A, B, C, D }

if I call list.remove(C), the list should now look like { A, B, D }

Answer (score 0):

You could do this if you want to keep the same list.

```
int end = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    Object o = list.get(i);
    if (o != null)
        list.set(end++, o);
}
// remove the trailing values.
list.sublist(end, list.size()).clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should also work:

```
list.removeAll(Arrays.asList(null));
```